# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor vs System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference between Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken classes? When to use which?.